# How to set UISearchController active Without animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I want to make a function. When I click a cell called 'search history message', and then navigationController push a new controller which shows a search bar. the new controller like this:

[image]

I do not want any animation, so I need some suggestions.

Comment: try pushViewControllerAnimated:NO

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop animation of UIViewController push animation into the navigation controller, just set the animation param false.

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchvc animated:false];
```

another thing is that, you can stop the search active animation by calling 'layoutIfNeeded' on 'self.view' .

```
//activate your search option
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

this will make necessary frame changes without any animation.